# How to encapsulate (and namespace) existing big javascript file without modifying it?

Tags: javascript, wsdl, cxf

## Abstract

I have a huge JS file that has old-style function and variable definition: it puts everything to the global scope. I would like to be able to 'import' that file in a 'namespace' so the global scope stays nice and clean.

## Details

The 'huge file' is a Web Service client generated by WSDL2JS tool from Apache CXF. It puts hundreds of functions and variables to the global scope, there is a small [sample of that file on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xvxeH6we). I would like to keep using that tool but keep the generated JS in some kind of a namespace or separate scope. Is it possible to do with some tools or minimum manual intervention?

## Sample

That's the code from WSDL2JS wrapped in self-invoking function that is actually not working.
Can be tested and edited on http://jsfiddle.net/rozboris/26t5nwmx/

```
var testModule = (function(){
  //here starts the generated code that I don't want to touch
  function priv(){
    console.log('called private function');
  }

  function proto(){
    this.something = 'hello';
  }

  priv.prototype = new proto;
  //here ends the generated code that I don't want to touch

  return {
    priv: priv
  }

})();

testModule.priv.something; //undefined
```

## Side question

Is there a better tool to use a wsdl-based webservice from JS (in the browser)? Is there an alternative to WSDL2JS from Apache CXF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. You will absolutely have to modify the file itself, although it can be done automatically. Basically just wrap it in an IEFE and put some export code for those variables that you still want to be global.

Comment: @Bergi, the problem is that all these functions and variables depend on each other, so exposing just one or two does not help. Is there any way to just put all that mess to a namespace with a separate tool? Modifying JS file is ok, unless it's automatic.

Comment: You don't want a "namespace" (which means dotted access on an object in JavaScript), you just want a *scope* (which my solution offers you).

Comment: @Bergi how can your solution help here http://jsfiddle.net/rozboris/26t5nwmx/ ?

Comment: testModule.priv() should work in the sample code you provided

Comment: @bedane, it works, but I also need to access .something from proto(). It's how CXF generates the code.

Comment: @Rozboris: the problem is not the iefe, it's your code: Use `(new testModule.priv).something`. However, your inheritance is buggy anyway.

Comment: @Bergi, you are right, it totally works like that! Yay! Thank you! Can you submit it as an answer so I can accept it? the inheritance comes from Apache CXF, I wish there was a better tool.

Comment: @Rozboris: No, I found bedane already has answered your question fine, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you need to call its functions from outside? If not, it's only a matter of enclosing your existing code in an [immediately evaluated function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
(function(){
    //code goes here
}());
```

and adding 'var' inside in front of every global declaration.

Comment: I call some functions of course. And these functions call other 'internal' functions from that file, so I will have to expose the whole thing.

Comment: Then only expose the functions you need to call from outside using the revealing module pattern. A simple implementation example: http://toddmotto.com/mastering-the-module-pattern/

Comment: Thanks to you and @Bergi [above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016896/how-to-encapsulate-and-namespace-existing-big-javascript-file-without-modifyin#comment40751693_26016896) I managed to get it work exactly this way. Thank you.